# QuickSelect Algorithm

Tags: python, recursion, partitioning

I'm currently doing an assignment for my computer science class, and I can't figure out what is wrong with my code to perform quick select.

```py
def partition(a_list, first, last):
    pivot = a_list[last]
    i = first-1
    for j in range(first, last):
        if a_list[j] <= pivot:
            i += 1
            a_list[i], a_list[j] = a_list[j], a_list[i]
    a_list[i+1], a_list[last] = a_list[last], a_list[i+1]
    print(a_list)
    return i+1

def selection(a_list, first, last, k):
    pivot = a_list[last]
    pivotIndex = partition(a_list, first, last)
    if first == last:
        return a_list[k]
    elif k <= pivotIndex:
        return selection(a_list, first, pivotIndex-1, k)
    else:
        return selection(a_list, pivotIndex+1, last, k - pivotIndex)

print(selection([5,4,1,10,8,3,2], 0, 6, 1))
print(selection([5,4,1,10,8,3,2], 0, 6, 3))
print(selection([5,4,1,10,8,3,2], 0, 6, 6))
print(selection([5,4,1,10,8,3,2], 0, 6, 7))
print(selection([46, 50, 16, 88, 79, 77, 17, 2, 43, 13, 86, 12, 68, 33, 81, \
74, 19, 52, 98, 70, 61, 71, 93, 5, 55], 0, 24, 19))
```

After the third print statement my code just get stuck in a loop, and eventually dies because maximum recursions have been reached. The first output should also be 1, and I understand why it's doing that. But I can't figure out a solution to fix it.

This is my output, before it eventually gives me the error maximum recursion depths reached. (Ignore the list being printed, it's just there so I can see what it's partitioning)

```py
[1, 2, 5, 10, 8, 3, 4]
2
[1, 2, 5, 10, 8, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 10]
3
[1, 2, 5, 10, 8, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 8, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 8, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10]
```

Comment: You are being very complicated here, what are you trying to do? Your recursion is not ending so first is never equal to last.

Answer (score 1):

The `partition` function seems fine to me. The main issues have to do with the `selection` function. They are:

1. Mixing 0-indexing and 1-indexing
2. Checking bounds of `selection` function
3. Handling the `k` value for recursion

### Point 1: mixing 0-indexing and 1-indexing

This example shows it:

```
print(selection([5,4,1,10,8,3,2], 0, 6, 1))
```

You said in your question that the expected output was `1`. The list `[5,4,1,10,8,3,2]` sorted is `[1,2,3,4,5,8,10]` . In the call to the `selection` function, you supplied `0` and `6` as `first` and `last` respectively. These 2 variables use 0-indexing. For `k` however, you supplied `1` and expected the output of the `selection` function to be `1`. This makes use of 1-indexing.

There's nothing wrong with that, but things can get confusing quickly. We should standardize things. I choose to use 0-indexing for `k`.

### Point 2: Checking bounds of `selection` function

In particular, this statement:

```
if first == last:
```

should be changed to:

```
if first >= last:
```

because of the below statements:

```
elif k <= pivotIndex:
    return selection(a_list, first, pivotIndex-1, k)
else:
    return selection(a_list, pivotIndex+1, last, k - pivotIndex)
```

it is possible that `first >= pivotIndex - 1` and `pivotIndex + 1 >= last` in either of those 2 recursive calls to `selection`. In those cases, we know that there is only 1 element remaining in the sublist, so we should just return it.

### Point 3: Handling the `k` value for recursion

In this statement:

```
return selection(a_list, pivotIndex+1, last, k - pivotIndex)
```

It's not necessary to subtract `pivotIndex` from `k`. Even though the next `selection` call only takes into account of the sublist from `pivotIndex+1` to `last` (inclusive), we are not creating a new array containing only the elements from `a_list[pivotIndex+1]` to `a_list[last]`, and hence the element we are interested in will still be at position `k`.

### With those changes

We can keep the `partition`function as it is. Here's an updated `selection` function:

```
def selection(a_list, first, last, k):
    # Handle possibility that first >= last, so we only have
    # one element remaining in the sublist
    if first >= last:
        return a_list[k]
    pivot = a_list[last]
    pivotIndex = partition(a_list, first, last)
    if k < pivotIndex:
        return selection(a_list, first, pivotIndex-1, k)
    else:
        # k is left as it is
        return selection(a_list, pivotIndex+1, last, k)
```

You should change the calls to `selection` to use 0-indexing for `k`.

Hope that helps!